# Is there a concept of "absolute" or "uniform" convergence for two-sided improper integrals?

Tags: terminology, improper-integrals

Consider an (improper) integral like
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x^4 \sin x}{x^2+1}dx
$$
If we treat this as the sum of two separate one-sided improper integrals 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{a} \frac{x^4 \sin x}{x^2+1}dx + \int_{a}^{+\infty} \frac{x^4 \sin x}{x^2+1}dx
= \lim_{t\to-\infty}\int_{t}^{a} \frac{x^4 \sin x}{x^2+1}dx
+ \lim_{u\to+\infty}\int_{a}^{u} \frac{x^4 \sin x}{x^2+1}dx
$$
then we should say the original integral does not converge, since neither of these two limits exists.

But if we treat this as the limit of a two-sided integral
$$
= \lim_{s\to\infty}\int_{-s}^{s} \frac{x^4 \sin x}{x^2+1}dx
$$
then this limit exists and in fact is zero.

Do we say that such a 2-sided integral converges or diverges?  And either way, is there terminology for an improper integral such that for some joint approaches to $\pm \infty$ of its endpoints the integral converges, yet for others it does not?

For example, if 
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 
\frac{x^4 \sin x}{x^2+1} & x\geq 0
\\\frac{16x^4 \sin 2x}{4x^2+1} & x<0
\end{array}\right.
$$
we would have, for $d(s) = -\frac{s}{2}$ and $u(s) = s$,
$$
\lim_{s->\infty}\left[  \int_{d(s)}^0f(x)\,dx + \int_0^{u(s)}f(x)\,dx \right] = 0
$$
while for  $d(s) = -s$ and $u(s) = s$,
$$
\lim_{s->\infty}\left[  \int_{d(s)}^0f(x)\,dx + \int_0^{u(s)}f(x)\,dx \right] 
$$ diverges.
So for this example, if we insist on taking the two endpoints to $\pm\infty$ together, the integral converges or diverges depending on how we take those endpoints to infinity. Is there a name for this sort of integral?

Comment: [Cauchy-Principle Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: this integral doesn't converge

Comment: As Graubner says it does not converge but the function is odd so any sub-integral from -R to R will be 0. If it would converge it would therefore have to be 0.